# Lambda expression for outer joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I want to write a lambda equivalent for

```
from col in db.Collectors
  join f in db.Files
on new { col.CollectorCode, col.StatusID }
  equals new { f.CollectorCode, StatusID = 1 } into f_join
from f in f_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
  col.FileID == null
orderby
  col.CollectorCode
select new {
  col.CollectorCode,
  col.Name
}
```

I have a table collector and table file. Table files contains multiple records(files) for each collector and I want to retrieve only the collectors that do not have records in table files.

I am not clear how to do it.

This is what I have, but is not working as expected:

```
db.Collectors.Join(
                db.Files,
                col => col.CollectorCode,
                f => f.CollectorCode,
                (col, f) => new { Collector = col });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple `Where` clause:

```
db.Collectors.Where(c => !db.Files.Any(f => f.CollectorCode == c.CollectorCode));
```

I use `Any` in the inner query so it will "short-circuit" when a match is found. There may be a more efficient approach, but this will work.

Comment: That wouldn't result in a left outer join, no.  A left outer join would mean that there is a record in the result set for every item in the left set (in this case, collectors) and if there is more than one match in the right set (files here) then there is that many records in the result set for that, corresponding to each pairing.  This doesn't create that structure.  The whole point of the question is that he has a working query (in query syntax) and just wants to know how to write it in method syntax.

Comment: @Servy, I couldn't understand his "join" logic, so I went with this statement:  "I want to retrieve only the collectors that do not have records in table files." It didn't sound right to me either, but I felt like that was the question. Since i didn't know the correct translation, I wrote the method I would use if I wrote it from scratch. I agree that your answer is the best translation and "intent" of the question (hence my upvote).

Comment: @Servy you may be right, but it worked as I wanted! thank you

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, that's correct, may be I was going with the wrong approach, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `join ... into` query syntax code corresponds to `GroupJoin`, not `Join`.

```
db.Collectors.GroupJoin(
    db.Files,
    col => col.CollectorCode,
    f => f.CollectorCode,
    (col, f_join) => new { col, f_join })
```

And any `from` clauses after the first will correspond to `SelectMany`:

```
db.Collectors.GroupJoin(...)
    .SelectMany(join => join.f_join.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(f => new{join.col, f}))
    //...
```

Personally, with a query like this that needs to propagate information projected from previous operations "past" another operation tends to be much clearer in query syntax than method syntax, due to the need in method syntax here to constantly be projecting everything out into anonymous types with all of the pieces of data to hold onto.